# Stockfish Transposition Table: 16 bit key equals 0 even if the key is found?

Tags: stockfish, tablebases, transpositions

In Stockfish 11, they [use the high 16 bits as key inside the cluster](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/4b10578acbe099482ed40200478df4d775c01af5/src/tt.cpp#L124):

```
const uint16_t key16 = key >> 48;  // Use the high 16 bits as key inside the cluster
```

This renders problem when key >> 48 equals 0 (for example: key=32401393425620 >> 48 = 0), then the function return found = false, even when found should be true.

```
return found = (bool)tte[i].key16, &tte[i];
```

Recently, they update: [Use the low 16 bits as key inside the cluster](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/1ea488d34c0b6a03fa3d89d289fe72fd1408cafd/src/tt.cpp#L120)

```
const uint16_t key16 = (uint16_t)key;  // Use the low 16 bits as key inside the cluster
```

But I think it doesn't guarantee the low 16 bits won't be 0 after converted from 64 bit key.

So this function is wrong? I guess they want to save memory so that they only 16 bits, but what's the point of saving if the function wrong?